# How do I check if a Javascript array contains all the other elements of another array

Tags: javascript

If I have one array:

```
let x=  [0,1,2,3,5]
```

And I have an array with several subarrays:

```
let winningIndices = [[0, 1, 2], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]
```

How can I check if array x contains all of the elements of any one subarray.

In other words, how can I check if array x has combinations of either the numbers 0,1,2 or 6,7,8...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any code to show on your current approach?

Comment: I see you took out the tic-tac-toe part. But I'm not seeing a code attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: It's your data structure that is causing the headache (for you). Without the "tic-tac-toe" context, you could very well get an answer that logically works, but doesn't solve the problem. ... Consider using a 2 dimensional array for the board.

Comment: @GetSet The one dimensional array worked pretty well, I just needed a function to compare the array. Thank you for the assistance

Answer (score 3):

"How can I check if array x contains all of the elements of any one subarray."

Here's the most straightforward functional interpretation.

```
const won = winningIndices.some(indices=>
    indices.every(
        item=>x.includes(item)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be an option. If you'd like to remove xIncludesItem key from result, just map it again.

```js
const winningIndices = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

const x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5];

const result = winningIndices
  .map((item) => {
    const xIncludesItem = item
      .map((i) => x.includes(i))
      .every(includes => includes);
    return { item, xIncludesItem };
  })
  .filter(result => result.xIncludesItem);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.includes is much slower than [Set.has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has).  A slightly more performant solution based on Ted Brownlow's solution would be:

```
const setX = new Set(x);
const won = winningIndices.some(indices=>
    indices.every(
        item=>setX.has(item)
    )
)
```